# Перевод из паскаля в С++

Tags: pascal, c++

Народ проблема с переводом...

```
Program LAB3_7;
    Var
         x,f,eps,a,n:real;
    Begin
      Write('Введите значение аргумента: x = ');
      Readln(x);
      Write('Введите значение точности: eps = ');
      Readln(eps);
       f:=x; A:=1; n:=1;
       repeat
        a:=(a*x*x)/(n*(n+1));
        f:=f+a;
        n:=n+2;
       until abs(a)<eps;
       Writeln('Ответ: ch(x) = ',f);
    End.
```

Comment: автор, вы же ведь совсем-совсем не хотите, чтобы это сделали за вас, не так ли?

Comment: после нескольких часов заседаний дум я так и не понял как правильно перевести в С++ цикл...

Comment: 'Program LAB3_7', а не нарушаете ли вы правила использования ресурса?
Слишком, ну слишком просто, чтобы на такое отвечать...

Comment: >после нескольких часов заседаний дум я так и не понял как правильно перевести в С++ цикл...

это, товарищи, п***ец...Вот честное слово, иначе не скажешь...куда, в общем, страна катится

Comment: Если вдаваться в подробности то сама задача решена и как такого решения мне не нужно я лишь пытаюсь узнать как мне правильно перевести из паскаля в с++ сам цикл ибо я плохо знаю с++ и делаю первые шаги в нем...

Comment: а что вам мешает прочитать первые 10-20 страниц любой книжки по С++ для начинающих, где это все описано? Я вас уверяю, первые 10-20 страниц этих книжек очень просты и трудностей у вас не вызовут. Я боюсь, что мешает вам только элементарная лень. Так или иначе, здесь не любят, когда кто-то просит готовое решение элементарной задачи

Comment: Repeat ... until в Паскале соответствует циклу Do ... While в C++. Вот вам чтиво: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0kk5few.aspx
Осилить его не трудно, поэтому уж потрудитесь на радость нам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

делаю принципиально, не чтобы решить за автора, а чтобы самому вспомнить с++ :))
Могу ошибаться, но:

> Var
>            x,f,eps,a,n:real;

```
float x;  
float f; ...
```

---

> Write('Введите значение аргумента: x = ');

```
cout << 'Введите значение аргумента: x = ' << endl;
```

---

> Readln(x);

```
cin >> x;
```

---

> repeat
>     ...
>     until (условие);

```
do
{
...
}
while(!условие);
```

---

И, как всегда, сообщаю о том, что гугл кишмя кишит ответами на данный вопрос. Одна из первых ссылок выборки [указывает на стэк](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077216/how-do-you-make-a-repeat-until-loop-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

N:Integer;
X,a,c,h,S:Real;

на с++ это значит

int N;
float X, a, c, h, S;